# When linux send ack while hook on recv with ptrace

Tags: c, linux, tcp, arm, ptrace

I hook on syscall `recv` /`recvfrom` at that communication TCP with `ptrace` (PTRACE_SYSCALL) in linux Arm architecture and tried to modify the incoming data(modify data and size or incoming data)

When the system send ACK to packet? Before I catch it with PRTACE_SYSCALL or after? If I modify the data that catched in those syscall is that problem because it is TCP communication?

Comment: The kernel sends an ACK as soon as it has saved the packet in its transmit buffer.  `read()`/`recv()`/`recvfrom()` etc. functions (or more precisely, their underlying syscalls) simply copy the data from the transmit buffer.  So, the ACK happens much earlier, and ptracer modifying the data in the buffer when the syscall returns is not a problem.  You can even change the number of bytes returned (discarding some of the data, or appending some if there is room in the buffer).